# A fair 4-sided die (with number 1, 2, 3, 4) is thrown 8 times. What is the probability at least one number occurs exactly once?

Tags: probability

So I was thinking whether the answer should be $\frac{4*8*3^7}{4^8}$, however, the $3^
{7}$ might be wrong since the probability that what I get was over 1, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The negation of this event is "every number occurs either $0$ times or $2+$ times". Now, this can be broken into cases based on how many numbers occur a non-zero number of times.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the total population, and you need the different cases where there's a single occurrence of some number or numbers. For any given *multiplicity pattern* of the occurrence of numbers, there will be a [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) giving ways to arrange it and a multinomial of ways to fill with particular digits. Breaking this down by multiplicity patterns that include a $1$:

- $(7,1,0,0)$ selected $\binom 4{2,1,1}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{7,1}$ ways
- $(6,1,1,0)$ selected $\binom 4{2,1,1}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{6,1,1}$ ways
- $(5,2,1,0)$ selected $4!$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{5,2,1}$ ways
- $(5,1,1,1)$ selected $\binom 4{3,1}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{5,1,1,1}$ ways
- $(4,3,1,0)$ selected $4!$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{4,3,1}$ ways
- $(4,2,1,1)$ selected $\binom 4{2,1,1}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{4,2,1,1}$ ways
- $(3,3,1,1)$ selected $\binom 4{2,2}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{3,3,1,1}$ ways
- $(3,2,2,1)$ selected $\binom 4{2,1,1}$ ways, arranged $\binom 8{3,2,2,1}$ ways

Multiply selection by arrangement in each case and add across cases.

Answer (score 0):

You counted number of favorable arrangements as $4 \cdot 8 \cdot 3^7$ but it has duplicates. Just as an example - As part of $4 \choose 1$, say you choose $1$ to be the number that  occurs once. Now $3^7$ will include arrangements where $2$ occurs once. But when you choose $2$ to be the number that occurs once, $3^7$ will include arrangements that have $1$ occur once. So there is overcounting of cases when $1$ and $2$ occur once. This is just one example of how there are duplicates in your solution. Applying Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, number of favorable cases are

$\displaystyle \small 4 \times 8 \times 3^7 - {4 \choose 2} \cdot {8 \choose 2} \cdot 2! \cdot 2^6 + 4 \cdot {8 \choose 3} \cdot 3! = 49824$

First term is what you wrote. The second term is to subtract overcounting (duplicates) of cases where *two* numbers occur once. Third term is to add back cases where *three* numbers occur once as they get undercounted after subtraction of second term.

Comment: @Iso, any reaction to any of the answers? Does this answer and / or others help you understand your mistake?